# this.props.navigation loses value when called in my POST method

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-ios

inside my register page I have a method that gets called and register's a user. However when I try to navigate back to the login page after registering the user I get **Cannot read property 'navigation' of undefined**. My code is

```
sendAjax = () => {
  //this.props.navigation returns a value and I can navigate to 'Login'

  if(!Regex.test(this.state.email)){
  }else if(this.state.password != this.state.confirmPwd){
    Alert.alert("The passwords don't match!");
  }else{
    const fn = encodeURIComponent(this.state.firstname);
    ...
    const hashDigest = sha256(p);
    const requestBody = `firstname=${fn}...

    //POST
    fetch("http://localhost:3000/users", {
        method: "POST",
        mode: "cors",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        },
        body: requestBody
    }).then(function (res, next) {
        console.log("fetch request ", JSON.stringify(res.ok));
        if(res.ok){
            res.json().then(function (json) {
                if(json.registerstate){
                    Alert.alert('Register success, please login');
                    //Cannot read property 'navigation' of undefined
                    this.props.navigation.navigate('Login')
                }
            });
        }
    })
    .then((res) => {
      Alert.alert("then working");
    })
    ....
  }
}
```

I'm not sure why this.props.navigation.navigate becomes undefined halfway down the method, yet at the beginning I could call it. Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: Don't use a regular function! Use an arrow function!

Comment: Hey @AndrewLi I think I am using an arrow function ( sendAjax = () => {} )

Comment: No: `.then(function (res, next) {`, and `.then(function (json) {`

Comment: Ah okay, didn't know you needed to - thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is that "this" is changing for you.  Using arrow functions keeps the "outer this" in scope, instead of the "this" changing because of being in a new function.